# How to properly design the SQL table for this specific data information?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I'm trying to figure out how to properly design an SQL table that holds the following information: a group id (unique integer), a group name and the members for each group (i.e. strings which represents names of group members.
For example, you might have a group "Family", which has the group id 1121, and has Jay, Aviva, Mat and Dana, in it, and another possible group might be "Best Friends" with group id 1123 and has Mat, Dilan and Jack in it).
So, at first I thought about having one table with scheme (Group_ID, Group_Name, Members), but I don't have an upper bound on the number of members in the group, and it feels like a bad idea in general anyway.
Does anyone have an idea on how else can I save this information in a relational DB?
Or maybe I should consider saving this information in an XML file instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to have 3 tables

```
groups table
------------
id  |   name
------------
1   |  family
2   |  friends


users table
-----------
id  |  name
-----------
1   |  peter
2   |  tom


members table
--------------------
group_id  |  user_id
--------------------
1         |  1
1         |  2 
2         |  2
```

If you then would like to get all members of the group "family" you can run the query

```
select u.name
from users u
join members m on m.user_id = u.id
join groups g on m.group_id = g.id
where g.name = 'family'
```

Comment: The members table could be a problem, because one member can be associated with two or more groups... EDIT wait... so I should have an entry for each member's association?